# Multiple mathematical operations on a file containing numbers

Tags: sed, scripting

I have extracted the following data using 'grep' & 'sed' pipes from a file and now I want to perform a mathematical equation on the last two numbers, delete them and replace them with a single number.

Mathematical operations

```
Add the numbers together
divide by 2
multiply by 141
ROUNDUP to whole number
```

File Data

```
AJ29 IO_0_VRN_10 77.234 78.011
AJ30 IO_L1P_T0_100M 89.886 90.789
AJ31 IO_L1N_T0_100S 101.388 102.406
AK29 IO_L2P_T0_101M 66.163 66.828
AL29 IO_L2N_T0_101S 63.626 64.266
```

So the line starting AJ29 should appear as:

```
AJ29 IO_0_VRN_10 10945
```

I could put it in MS excel / Open Office calc and do this but want to avoid MS and keep it in a single linux script if it is possible.  Hope you can help.  The script I have so far is below and ideally I'd like to add a few more pipes to achieve this.

```
grep IOB xc7vx690tffg1930.pkg | sed 's/pin//g' | sed 's/IOB_[A-Za-z0-9]*//g' | sed 's/ /-/g' | sed 's/\t//g' | sed 's/^[-]*//g' | sed 's/-/ /g' | sed 's/ [0-9][0-9] //g' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' | sed 's/,X[0-9A-Z]*,//g' | sed 's/,[0-9]*[A-Z],//g' | sed 's/N\.A\.,/,/g' | sed 's/,$//g' | sed 's/,/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculations, use `awk`!

```
$ awk '{$(NF-1)=sprintf("%.0f", ($(NF-1) + $NF)/2 * 141); NF--}1' file
AJ29 IO_0_VRN_10 10945
AJ30 IO_L1P_T0_100M 12738
AJ31 IO_L1N_T0_100S 14367
AK29 IO_L2P_T0_101M 9376
AL29 IO_L2N_T0_101S 9016
```

This replaces the penultimate field with the result of `(penultimate*last)/2 * 141)`. To make it round, we use `%.0f` format as indicated in [Awk printf number in width and round it up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131080/40596).

Also, it looks to me that you are piping way too many things: I counted one call to `grep` and 13 (!) to `sed`. You can probably use `sed -e 'first block' -e 'second block' ...` instead.

#### Explanation

In `awk`, `NF` refers to the number of fields on the current line. Since `$n` refers to the field number `n`, with `$(NF-1)` we refer to the penultimate field.

- `{...}1` do stuff and then print the resulting line. `1` evaluates as True and anything True triggers `awk` to perform its default action, which is to print the current line.
- `$(NF-1) + $NF)/2 * 141` perform the calculation: `(penultimate + last) / 2 * 141
- `{$(NF-1)=sprintf( ... )` assign the result of the previous calculation to the penultimate field. Using `sprintf` with `%.0f` we make sure the rounding is performed, as described above.
- `{...; NF--}` once the calculation is done, we have its result in the penultimate field. To remove the last column, we just say "hey, decrease the number of fields" so that the last one gets "removed".

Comment: This looks perfect, I will give it a go - thank you..  I'm not an experienced Linux user and did think I was doing a lot of piping but the original file format is quite complicated and contains a lot of information.

Comment: This looks perfect, I will give it a go - thank you @fedorqui  I'm not an experienced Linux user and did think I was doing a lot of piping but the original file format is quite complicated and contains a lot of information I don't want and this was the only way I could find to do it.  I'm sure there is an easier way.  Original format:  `pin IOB_X0Y49           AJ29            10  10  IO_0_VRN_10                     X51Y49    N.A.      77.234    78.011`

Comment: @Ad0m nice to read the answer was useful for you. If it solved your problem, consider accepting it. Regarding the number of pipes: consider editing the question if you want to go through the content, but do show a representative input together with a desired output for it.

Comment: Just to let you know @fedorqui that I just plugged your answer in after another pipe of course (haha) and it worked perfect.  I don't understand it so will have a read about awk but perfect cheers.  I've removed the pipes and put them in as you suggested (didn't know you could do that so thanks, again).  I'm still learning... All the best, cheers

Comment: @Ad0m nice words : ) I just edited my answer giving some explanation about how the `awk` works. Play with it a little bit, you'll see how cool it is to use `awk`! Cheers!!