# Search file A for a list of strings located in file B and append the value associated with that string to the end of the line in file A

Tags: bash, file, awk, sed

This is a bit complicated, well I think it is..

I have two files, File A and file B

File A contains delay information for a pin and is in the following format

```
AD22 15484
AB22 9485
AD23 10945
```

File B contains a component declaration that needs this information added to it and is in the format:

```
'DXN_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(AD22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
'DXP_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,AD23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
'VREFN_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(AB22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
```

So what I am trying to achieve is the following output

```
'DXN_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(AD22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
PIN_DELAY='15484';
'DXP_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,AD23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
PIN_DELAY='10945';
'VREFN_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(AB22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
PIN_DELAY='9485';
```

There is no order to the pin numbers in file A or B

So I'm assuming the following needs to happen

- open file A, read first line
- search file B for first string field in the line just read
- once found in file B at the end of the line add the text "\nPIN_DELAY='"
- add the second string filed of the line read from file A
- add the following text at the end "';"
- repeat by opening file A, read the second line

I'm assuming it will be a combination of sed and awk commands and I'm currently trying to work it out but think this is beyond my knowledge.  Many thanks in advance as I know it's complicated..

Comment: it would be interesting to show some of your efforts. [Not very long ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32411879/1983854) I posted an answer to a question of yours giving some comprehensive explanations that may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to the rescue...

```
$ awk -vq="'" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print; for(k in a) if(match($0,k)) {print "PIN_DELAY=" q a[k] q ";"; next}}' keys data 

'DXN_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(AD22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
PIN_DELAY='15484';
'DXP_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,AD23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
PIN_DELAY='10945';
'VREFN_0':
PIN_NUMBER='(AB22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)';
PIN_DELAY='9485';
```

Explanation: scan the first file for key/value pairs.  For each line in the second data file print the line, for any matching key print value of the key in the requested format.  Single quotes in awk is little tricky, setting a `q` variable is one way of handling it.

Comment: awk to the rescue indeed @karakfa, well done, I just fed this my code and it sorts it out in a few seconds, blinking brilliant.  It's great that you can see it working away to, processing the data (about 2000 pins in this case)..  The more I learn about Linux and awk I realise just how powerful it all is.  Unfortunately, I don't spend enough time using these sort of functions and hence the next time I need to do something I'd have forgotten what I have learned so I really appreciate the effort you have gone to, cheers and many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE2=`cat file2`
FILE1=`cat file1`
TMPFILE=`mktemp XXXXXXXX.tmp`
FLAG=0
for line in $FILE1;do
    echo $line >> $TMPFILE 
    for line2 in $FILE2;do
    if [ $FLAG == 1 ];then
        echo -e "PIN_DELAY='$(echo $line2 | awk -F " " '{print $1}')'" >> $TMPFILE
        FLAG=0
    elif [ "`echo $line | grep $(echo $line2 | awk -F " " '{print $1}')`" != "" ];then
        FLAG=1
    fi
    done
done
mv $TMPFILE file1
```

Works for me, you can also add a trap for remove tmp file if user send sigint.

Comment: Many thanks, just seeing if I can get it working my end - yeah, as I thought a little beyond my knowledge haha... Dunno how you get there so quick, amazing..

Comment: Hi @Glastis, many thanks for the answer to my question.  I have got it working and can see it beavering away by opening the XXX.tmp file every now and then.  The thing I neglected to mention was the size of these files (completely my fault).  There are over 2000 pins entries in the file and although I am confident it will do it, it is taking it's time.  This of course wasn't in my initial question so completely my fault. I have learned a bit more about file IO and "awk" from your code so I do appreciate the time you have taken to so this :)

Comment: Hi, (I post here because I can't post comment on your response), mktemp permit you to create a temporary file and echo its name, but it is really usefull to prevent new tmp file erase another tmp file with same name. If you want to prevent that, you should use a name like DELAYS.txt.XXXXX, mktemp will replace every 'x' by random char.

Comment: Ahh yes, yet another thing that is extremely useful and I did not know haha - I'll modify my script!!!  This is a good way to ensure this is seen as a temp file and should be ignored.. Many thanks for leaving this comment, I'm learning a little every day and have started a little log book with these useful things in them.  Really appreciate your help, thank you @Glastis

Answer (score 0):

FINAL Script for my application, A big thank you to all that helped..

```
# ! /usr/bin/sh

# script created by Adam with a LOT of help from users on stackoverflow

# must pass $1 file (package file from Xilinx)
# must pass $2 file (chips.prt file from the PCB design office)

# remove these temp files, throws error if not present tho, whoops!!
rm DELAYS.txt CHIP.txt OUTPUT.txt

# BELOW::create temp files for the code thanks to Glastis@stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101968/glastis I now know how to do this
DELAYS=`mktemp DELAYS.txt`
CHIP=`mktemp CHIP.txt`
OUTPUT=`mktemp OUTPUT.txt`

# BELOW::grep input file 1 (pkg file from Xilinx) for lines containing a delay in the form of n.n and use TAIL to remove something (can't remember), sed to remove blanks and replace with single space, sed to remove space before \n, use awk to print columns 3,9,10 and feed into awk again to calculate delay provided by fedorqui@stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui 

# In awk, NF refers to the number of fields on the current line. Since $n refers to the field number n, with $(NF-1) we refer to the penultimate field.
# {...}1 do stuff and then print the resulting line. 1 evaluates as True and anything True triggers awk to perform its default action, which is to print the current line.
# $(NF-1) + $NF)/2 * 141 perform the calculation: `(penultimate + last) / 2 * 141
# {$(NF-1)=sprintf( ... ) assign the result of the previous calculation to the penultimate field. Using sprintf with %.0f we make sure the rounding is performed, as described above.
# {...; NF--} once the calculation is done, we have its result in the penultimate field. To remove the last column, we just say "hey, decrease the number of fields" so that the last one gets "removed".

grep -E -0 '[0-9]\.[0-9]' $1 | tail -n +2 | sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]\+/ /g' -e 's/\s\n/\n/g' | awk '{print ","$3",",$9,$10}' | awk '{$(NF-1)=sprintf("%.0f", ($(NF-1) + $NF)/2 * 169); NF--}1' >> $DELAYS

# remove blanks in part file and add additional commas (,) so that the following awk command works properly
cat $2 | sed -e "s/[[:blank:]]\+//" -e "s/(/(,/g" -e 's/)/,)/g' >> $CHIP

# this awk command is provided by karakfa@stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa Explanation: scan the first file for key/value pairs. For each line in the second data file print the line, for any matching key print value of the key in the requested format. Single quotes in awk is little tricky, setting a q variable is one way of handling it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458680/search-file-a-for-a-list-of-strings-located-in-file-b-and-append-the-value-assoc
awk -vq="'" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print; for(k in a) if(match($0,k)) {print "PIN_DELAY=" q a[k] q ";"; next}}' $DELAYS $CHIP >> $OUTPUT

# remove the additional commas (,) added in earlier before ) and after ( and you are done..
cat $OUTPUT | sed -e 's/(,/(/g' -e 's/,)/)/g' >> chipsd.prt
```